# directly increment or decrement number update from column using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a query where in I use Eloquent for finding the ID but what I need is to directly subtract inside the eloquent query ? same as in Query Builder,

Documentation code

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

What I need is to directly to substract

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->value =- 1;

$flight->save();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use laravel `increment()` or `decrement()` method [see](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#increment-and-decrement)

```
App\Flight::find(1)->decrement('value',1);
```

second way u can achieve by `update` query

```
 App\Flight::where('id', 1)->update(['value' => \DB::raw('value - 1')]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->value = $flight->value-1;

$flight->save();
```

hope it helps! :)

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: This option is suitable if you want to retrieve the updated row id. The accepted answer is more suitable and clean if you just want to update and not get the id.